# How to add multiple responses into a single json object

Tags: python, json, flask

I am making some request to another site from my flask api. Basically my flask api is a proxy. So initially I substitute the parameters with the known company id and and get all the workers id. Given the workers id, I try to make another request which helps me get all their details. However with the code below I am only getting the last response which means only the details of the last worker. You can ignore the j==1 for now I did it for testing purposes.

```
tempDict={}
updateDic={}
dictToSend={}
 j=0
#i = companyid

#id=workerid

# I make several calls to url2 depending on the number of employee ids in number

for id in number:
    url2="someurl/" + str(i)+ "/contractors/"+str(id)
                r = requests.get(url2, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json',"Authorization":authenticate,'Accept': 'application/json'})
    print("id"+str(id))
    print(url2)

    loadJsonResponse2=json.loads(r.text)
    print(loadJsonResponse2)
    key = i


    tempDict.update(loadJsonResponse2)
    # I want to have all of their details and add the company number before            

    print(tempDict)

    if(j==1):
        dictToSend[key]=tempDict
        return jsonify(dictToSend)

    j=j+1





     return jsonify(dictToSend)
```

So I have all the workers ids and I request the other url to get all their details. The response is in json format. However I am only getting the last response with the above code. I did something like `j==1` because I wanted to check the return.

```
dictToSend[key]=tempDict
return jsonify(dictToSend)
```

The key is the company id so that I can identify which company the worker is from.

How can I get to concatenate all the json responses and at the end add a key like `"5":{concatenation of all json requests}`

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Your key for json object is

```
#i = companyid
.
.
.
 key = i
.
.
.
# You are adding all your responses to companyid,
# better make a key with companyid and workerid
# key = str(companyid) + ":" + str(workerid)
dictToSend[key]=tempDict
```

And here

```
# you may not need this, since there is already a loop iterating on workerid
if(j==1):
    dictToSend[key]=tempDict
    return jsonify(dictToSend)

j=j+1

# then only useful line would be 
dictToSend[key]=tempDict
```